# Prof says he'll write only limited number of recommendations

Tags: phd

I have a Master's degree and I am working as a project associate in an university. When I asked the Professor I am working with (PI of my project) for recommendation(for PhD applications) he said that he'll write only 4 recommendations.

What should I do now?

Comment: I can only offer my opinion - in some fields you should be able to find a PhD within four applications. Nevertheless, I would ask for a generic recommendation from the prof. that you can re-use. You will need more than one reference (probably) anyway, so if you can get two more references then it should not be too much of a problem with a generic ref from the prof. to ensure suspicion is not raised by any places you apply to.

Comment: Does the PI mean that he will write 4 rec. letters to 4 different students, or for 4 different applications of yours? If it's the latter, choose very wisely the 4 institution where you will apply.

Comment: @PsySp: It's the latter.

Comment: @SaravanaKumar Then you can only do as mentioned. Choose very wisely the 4 institutions where you will send your applications. 4 is an average number.

Comment: If the problem is the time requirement for writing new tailor-made letter, you could ask if he would be willing to forward a generic letter to more than 4 institutions